# Got an error "Not supportedException was unhandled by user code"

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, notsupportedexception

I have  table

```
  product(table name)
        product_id
        product_name 
        product_image
        product_price
        product_description
        category_id

  category(table name )
        category_id
        category_name 
        category_description
```

I have a combobox named it as `categoryCombobox` and grid view named it as `productgridview`

am trying to populate the datagrid depending upon the selection in the combobox.. like this ....

```
       private viod form_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        var products = from prods in abc.products
                       select new
                       {
                           prods.product_Id,
                           productname =  prods.product_Name,
                           productimage = prods.product_Image,
                           productprice = prods.product_Price,
                           productdescription = prods.product_Description

                       };
        productbindingsource.DataSource = products;
        productgridview.DataSource = productbindingsource;
        productgridview.Columns[0].Visible = false;
       }
       private void categoryCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

          // is this query correct 
          var categoryid = from productcategories in abc.categories
                         where productcategories.category_Name.Equals(categoryCombobox.Text)
                         select productcategories.category_Id;

          var produc = from pros in abc.products
                       where pros.Category_Id.Equals(categoryid)
                       select new
                       {
                           productname = pros.product_Name,
                           productimage = pros.product_Image,
                           productprice = pros.product_Price,
                           productdescription = pros.product_Description                                   

                       };
        productbindingsource.DataSource = produc;
        productgridview.DataSource = productbindingsource;
        productgridview.Columns[0].Visible = false;

    }
```

Got an error like this ......

ERROR : At this line    productbindingsource.DataSource = produc;

> Not supportedException  was unhaldled by user code
>   Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1'.
>   Only primitive types (such as Int32, String, and Guid) and entity
>   types are supported.

Comment: Going to need more information to be able to help, like the makeup of abc.products.

Comment: Which part of the error don't you understand?  It explains the problem quite clearly

Comment: @kieren if u understand pls try to solve this one still i am getting the same problem

Comment: Can you please edit to fix your formatting?

Comment: I'll say again "Which part of the error don't you understand?".. It says you can't compare elements of type `IQueryable` and that you must compare primitive types.  So, the problem is, you're trying to compare `IQueryable` objects..

Comment: its working now  Kieren......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var categoryid = from productcategories in abc.categories
                 where productcategories.
                           category_Name.Equals(categoryCombobox.Text)
                 select productcategories.category_Id;
```

Hover over `var` while debugging.  You will see that it is NOT an id as you expect, but an `IEnumerable`.  What you want to do is

```
// .First() trips the query and returns a single category_Id
var id = (from productcategories in abc.categories
         where productcategories.
                   category_Name.Equals(categoryCombobox.Text)
         select productcategories.category_Id).First();

var produc = from pros in abc.products
               where pros.Category_Id.Equals(id)
               select new
               {
                   productname = pros.product_Name,
                   productimage = pros.product_Image,
                   productprice = pros.product_Price,
                   productdescription = pros.product_Description                                   
               };
```

Notice `ids.First()`, which takes the first result from the initial query.

Comment: this is this is what i have got the problem when i am using your query  ERROR :  The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.

Comment: where pros.Category_Id.Equals(categoryid.FirstOrDefault())  I have used this query its working now.. many thanks for your support..

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to compare an int field against an enumerable set.

If the categoryID query will only return a single value, try this:

```
var produc = from pros in abc.products
                   where pros.Category_Id.Equals(categoryid.Single())
                   select new
                   {
                       productname = pros.product_Name,
                       productimage = pros.product_Image,
                       productprice = pros.product_Price,
                       productdescription = pros.product_Description                                   

                   };
```

If it's supposed to return a list of Ids, you'll want to write a single query with a join. I assume it's supposed to be single based on the name `categoryId`

edit - might not be 100% syntax correct

```
var produc = from pros in abc.products
    join cats in abc.categories on cats.category_id equals pros.Category_Id
    where cats.category_Name.Equals(categoryCombobox.Text)
    select new
    {
        productname = pros.product_Name,
        productimage = pros.product_Image,
        productprice = pros.product_Price,
        productdescription = pros.product_Description                                   
    };
```

Comment: No, that query returns IQueryable<T>. I edited with a linq query that does the join internally instead of two database round trips.